# Adding total row in forest plot R

Tags: r, r-forestplot, meta-analysis

In my forest plot using the forest function I want to express the total amount of controls (n.c) and events (n.c). Preferably this would be displayed in the last row below all the studies. How can I do this? My current code is:

The code for my meta-analysis:

```
HI<-metabin(event.e = n.HI_PT, n.e = n_PT, event.c = n.HI_T, n.c = n_T, data = HI_totals, sm = "rr", method = "MH", MH.exact = TRUE, fixed=FALSE, random = TRUE, method.tau = "PM", hakn = TRUE)

forest(HI, leftcols = c("author", "n.HI_PT", "n_PT", "n.HI_T", "n_T"), leftlabs = c("Study", "", "No. PT", "", "No. Term"), colgap.forest.left = "1cm", colgap.forest.right = "1cm", xlim = c(0.01, 10),     pooled.totals = TRUE, pooled.events = TRUE, col.square = "darkblue", col.diamond = "darkblue", col.diamond.random = "lightblue")
```